# Unable to connect database schema hibernate, gradle

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm unable to get spring boot to automatically load my database schema when I start it up.
I follow this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/#scratch

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root1
```

sakila it is a default database included in mysql 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrEq9.png)

Error:

```
Unable to create initial connections of pool
```

Comment: Have you included MySQL jdbc driver jar on your classpath?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like @PanayiotisPoularakis is right, and that's what You missed is this driver.